# Javascript File API get enconding

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I have input for file, and i want read this file and show to user.
Via

```
FileReader.readAsText(<File from input>, enconding)
```

i can read file, but how can i detect enconding of user file?

Comment: if you skip specifying encoding the file is read as UTF8.

Comment: Yes, but the user file can be in any encoding